# Full Outer Join not getting NULL values in the right side while they do exist in the left side

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have to compare between two sources EmployeeODS and EmployeeDWH to get new or deleted records like below :

```
SELECT bf.EmployeeId AS EmployeeIdODS
      ,bf.FunctionId AS FunctionIdODS
      ,bf.Scope AS ScopeODS
      ,bf.Primacy AS PrimacyODS
      ,bn.EmployeeId AS EmployeeIdDWH
      ,bn.FunctionId AS FunctionIdDWH
      ,bn.Scope AS ScopeDWH
      ,bn.Primacy AS PrimacyDWH
      ,bn.BI_StartDate
      ,bn.BI_EndDate
       FROM EmployeeODS bf
FULL OUTER JOIN EmployeeDWH bn ON bf.EmployeeId = bn.EmployeeId 
AND bf.FunctionId=bn.FunctionId 
AND bf.Scope=bn.Scope
WHERE bf.EmployeeId=15366
```

The output is like below :

```
EmployeeIdODS   FunctionIdODS   ScopeODS    PrimacyODS  EmployeeIdDWH   FunctionIdDWH   ScopeDWH    PrimacyDWH  BI_StartDate            BI_EndDate
15366           45              AMAGR       2           15366           45              AMAGR       2           2020-03-25              9999-12-31 
15366           940             AMATUN      1           15366           940             AMATUN      1           2020-03-25              9999-12-31
```

When I delete the record having the FunctionIdODS=45 and ScopeODS='AMAGR' from EmployeeODS :

```
DELETE FROM EmployeeODS WHERE EmployeeId=15366 AND Scope='AMAGR' AND FunctionId=45
```

I am getting this output :

```
EmployeeIdODS   FunctionIdODS   ScopeODS    PrimacyODS  EmployeeIdDWH   FunctionIdDWH   ScopeDWH    PrimacyDWH  BI_StartDate            BI_EndDate
15366           940             AMATUN      1           15366           940             AMATUN      1           2020-03-25              9999-12-31
```

My expected output :

```
EmployeeIdODS   FunctionIdODS   ScopeODS    PrimacyODS  EmployeeIdDWH   FunctionIdDWH   ScopeDWH    PrimacyDWH  BI_StartDate            BI_EndDate
NULL            NULL            NULL        NULL        15366           45              AMAGR       2           2020-03-25              9999-12-31 
15366           940             AMATUN      1           15366           940             AMATUN      1           2020-03-25              9999-12-31
```

Comment: `WHERE bf.EmployeeId=15366` this means bf.EmployeeId cannot be NULL

Comment: The `WHERE` still needs to be true. If `bf.EmployeeId=15366` doesn't evalualute to true, the row won't be displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is turning the `FULL JOIN` into a lesser type of outer join.

For `FULL JOIN`, I recommend filtering in subqueries:

```
   FROM (SELECT bf.*
         FROM EmployeeODS bf
         WHERE bf.EmployeeId = 15366
        ) FULL JOIN
        (SELECT bn.*
         FROM EmployeeDWH bn
         WHERE bn.EmployeeId = 15366
        ) bn
        ON bf.EmployeeId = bn.EmployeeId AND
           bf.FunctionId = bn.FunctionId AND
           bf.Scope = bn.Scope
```